# Why is this post deleted?

Tags: discussion

https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14703/i-want-to-upgrade-my-xiaomi-projector-by-buying-one-with-4k-resolution

The reasoning is that the requirement is not narrow enough.

But that doesn't make sense. The requirement is so narrow I am pretty much choosing between 1 out of 2 models.

Xiaomi Wemax A300 and Xiaomi Fengmi.

Normal google search does not give clear answer. They're both from xiaomi. Some uses Ansi lumen another uses lumen. I hardly found official website. It's not even in projector central yet. I latter found out that both are sub brand of xiaomi but even that isn't very clear.

So I want some reasoning which one is better.

As far as I know there is no other product that is cheaper and comparable with those 2. If possible I want to simply add requirements. That is, 4k, hdmi, price below $5k. Cost effective.

I ended up buying Wemax A300 and is pretty happy with it.

Comment: I really don't know, Although I can only read the titile, I think it should still be on the site.